# Remove the first elements of a path in XSLT

Tags: string, xslt, tokenize

I'm trying to remove the first 3 'tokens' of a path-looking string in XSLT 2.0.

For instance, go from `D:/FolderA/folderB/folderC/file.ext` to `folderC/file.ext`.

I cant find a quick idea to do it other than using a recursive function I'm struggling to write.

```
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedPath" select="(tokenize($url,'/'))" />
<xsl:value-of select="yy:restofpath($tokenizedPath,2)" />
```

where yy:restofpath could be something like:

```
<xsl:function name="yy:restofpath" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="pathtokens"/>
  <xsl:param name="startIndex"/>
  <xsl:variable name="length" select="count($pathtokens)"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="$pathtokens">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(.,yy:restofpath($pathtokens,),'')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>
```

This is a dumb function that I cant write, I'm confused how to process my tokenized string.

Maybe there is a simpler built-in way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
<xsl:variable name="tokenizedPath" select="tokenize($url,'/')" />
```

then you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join($tokenizedPath[position() gt 3], '/')"/>
```

Comment: awesome, simple Xpath, great! Thanks a lot!